# Troubles calculating the correct rotation angle for an arc in jetpack compose

Tags: java, android, math, android-jetpack-compose, android-canvas

## Current State

I am currently playing around with an app where I am displaying multiple arcs in a circle.
[Center circle with 6 arcs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHIlP.png)

When you tap on one of the arcs, the arcs get rotated so that the tapped arc is on the bottom(90 degree) and a second layer of arcs appears with multiple arcs.

[Second layer with 8 arcs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fc12u.png)

When you click in the second layer of arcs, the same rotation happens for this layer. Additionally when one arc is in focus(meaning 90 degrees is in it's boundaries), it scales and it's sweep angle gets the same as the one from the inner circle.

[Tapped arc is now in focus on sweep angle is the same as the one from inner circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdiBJ.png)

Since the arc in focus gets "wider", all other arcs get smaller:

- Arc width before anything is in focus: 360/8 = 45
- Width of arc in focus = 60
- Width of all other arcs not in focus = ~42.86

When there is at least one arc in focus, it's easy to calculate how to rotate:

```kotlin
fullAngle = 360
rotation=current rotation offset if the layer already rotated
arc=arc which is tapped on
...
        val currentMiddleAngle = getCenteredAngleOfCurrentItem(arc, rotation, fullAngle)
        var angleToRotate = 0f;
        if (isItemCenterInLeftTopAndBottomQuarter(currentMiddleAngle)) {
            angleToRotate = currentMiddleAngle - 90f
        } else if (isItemCenterInRightTopQuarter(currentMiddleAngle, fullAngle)) {
            angleToRotate = fullAngle - currentMiddleAngle + 90
        } else if (isItemInRightBottomQuarter(currentMiddleAngle)) {
            angleToRotate = 90 - currentMiddleAngle
        }
        return angleToRotate
...
private fun getCenteredAngleOfCurrentItem(
        arc: PieChartInput,
        rotation: Float,
        fullAngle: Float
    ): Float {
        val middleOfItemAngel = arc.angleToDraw / 2
        val currentMiddleAngle =
            (arc.currentStartAngle + rotation + middleOfItemAngel).mod(fullAngle)
        return currentMiddleAngle
    }
```

The above code works fine if there is already one arc in focus and the other ones are smaller. If an arc is on the right half of the circle, it rotates clockwise. In the other case it rotates counter clockwise.

## Problem

My problem is when the second layer expands the first time, no arc is selected(this is intended). If there is a tap on one of the arcs then, this arc should move to bottm center(90 degrees)

I tried different calculations, but there is always some difference and its not rotated to the center correctly

That's how it looks when I tap all the arcs on the right side. I added some numbers to easily identify them.

[Before Tap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmcLp.png) [Tap on second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1iZH6.png)

What I don't understand is why the "offset" gets bigger, when the taped arc is further away from 90 degrees.

Of course the left part of the circle has a similar issue

I tried to add the the difference between the width of an selected item and the width when no item is selected, but this only helped for one of the arcs. The others still had the wrong offset.

I know there has to be a "simple" formular to calculate this. But after days of thinking, my brain won't show me the correct solution.

**Update**
A selected arc "grows" clockwise when the current rotation direction is clockwise. This means, if an arc gets in focus, the start angle does not change, only the end angle. If current rotation is counter clockwise, the arc also grows counter clockwise

Comment: The width of all the other arcs should be (360 - 60) / 7 degrees, which is about 42.86, not 50.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem you are right, miscalculation for the question. I will adapt the question. Thanks